# Looping over all lexicographical successive numbers

Tags: c, optimization, bit-manipulation, micro-optimization

For given bit vector `first` of length `bitnum` (<32) I need to iterate over all lexicographical successive bit vectors of same length.

For example, if `first` is 011001 (binary) and `bitnum` is 6, then all successive are: 011011, 011101, 011111, 111001, 111011, 111101, 111111. Also, I need to iterate over 011001 too.

What I mean lexicographical successive:

- if the i-th bit in `first` was '1', then i-th bit of `next` must be '1'
- if the i-th bit in `first` was '0', then i-th bit of `next` can be '0' or '1'

*What is the fastest way of generating such bit vectors?*

Now I use this unoptimized code, It works by generating all possible bit vectors and check every vector is it follow the given `first` in lexicographical way.

```
uint32_t loop_over_all_lex_succ(int bitnum, uint32_t first) {
    uint32_t next = first;
    uint32_t tmp;
    do { 
      target_function(next);

      do {
        next++;
        tmp = (~first|next); // sets the 0 bit at offset iff `next` has a 0 bit and `first` has 1
        tmp = ~tmp; // invert tmp; now all invalid bits are marked with '1'
        tmp = tmp & ((1<<bitnum)-1); // mask the tmp with target bit number

      } while( (next < (1<<bitnum))  && tmp );

    } while ( next < (1<<bitnum) );
}
```

I think, that if code will generate only successive bit vectors, it will be faster.

`First` vectors are any possible vector with this bit length.

Ordering of generated vectors can be different.

If you want to benchmark this function or your versions of it, there is a small benchmarker, just add a loop.. function code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t count =0;
void target_function(uint32_t a) { count++; }
/* loop_over_all_lex_succ() here */
int main() {
    uint32_t f;
    int bitnum=16;  // you can increase it up to 31
    for(f=0;f<(1<<bitnum);f++)
        loop_over_all_lex_succ(bitnum,f);
    printf("bits: %d,  count of pairs: %u\n",bitnum,count);
}
```

For example for bitnum=16 this code runs 6 sec on my PC. I need to use this function with higher bit count, up to 31.

Please, help me optimize `loop_over_all_lex_succ`.

Comment: I’m not sure that I understood what you want: do you want to iterate over all numbers greater than the input, that also have the same bits set, i.e. that don’t un-set any of the bits that are set in the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest a brute force approach that seems simpler and possibly more efficient than the one in the original question:

```
uint32_t loop_over_all_lex_succ(int bitnum, uint32_t first) {
    const uint32_t last = 1 << bitnum;
    uint32_t value;

    for (value = first;
         value < last;
         value = (value + 1) | first)
    {
        target_function(value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

On my 2.67 GHz Core i7 MacBook Pro, the code in the question runs in 2.1 s, whereas the above code runs in 0.04 s, for a speed-up of around 50x.

Comment: @osgx: re-reading your question, it's not totally clear, but are you saying that the 1 bits in `first` must always remain as 1, whereas the 0 bits can each be 0 or 1 ? Is that what lexicographical means in this context ?

Comment: Yes. All 1 bit from `first` must stay as 1 in all `next`, and 0 bits form `first` can be a 0 or 1 bit in `next`. I think, it is like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order of bit vectors (ordered sets of bits).

Comment: @osgx: OK - thanks - that was the part that was not clear (to me) in the original question - maybe you could change the initial 4 bit example so that it covers a non-contiguous range of values ?

Comment: @osgx: yes, except it would make more sense (to me, at least) to list the output in numeric order, including `first`, so I would give the output for the example as follows: `011001, 011011, 011101, 011111, 111001, 111011, 111101, 111111`.

Comment: @osgx: sorry - must not post untested code (do I never learn ?). Unfortunately it's now slower... :-(

Comment: Bit modified your code - see second answer. I say that using while is better for this task.

Comment: @osgx: see above for improved version - we now have a preflight check to generate minimum increment and we no longer backtrack over old values after finding a new value. This one is *much* faster.

Comment: @Paul R, thanks for your answer, you really helped me to get a right one. Can you compare my answer and your for some bigger bitsize, e.g. 20 or 22 ?

Comment: @osgx: sure - for 20 bits I get 8 mins 45 secs = 525 secs with the original code, and with my code it's 5.7 secs, so that's a 90x speed up !

Comment: And what about code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244968/looping-over-all-lexicographical-successive-numbers/5245986#5245986

Comment: @osgx: yours is faster: 2.2 secs !

Comment: @osgx: I just realised the test in the loop in my code is now redundant, so I removed that and the time has come down to 2.7 secs. Yours is still faster at 2.2 secs.

Comment: loop to find an increment is also redundant. You can use 1, because if `first` have 1111 at the end, the carry will move 1 around them.

Comment: @osgx: true - I should remove that now - time is now down to 2.2s at 20 bits - essentially the same solution as yours now, but with a for loop instead of a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
uint32_t loop_over_all_lex_succ(int bitnum, uint32_t first) {
    uint32_t next = first;
    uint32_t tmp;
    do { 
      target_function(next);
      next = (next +1 ) |first;
    } while ( next < (1<<bitnum) );
}
```

Here we do an increment, but also we reset all 1 bits from `first` at every step. With such code we will increment only bits, which were `0` in first.

Comment: `next = (next + 1) | first` seems like the straightforward, obviously-correct answer.

Comment: @caf, it was not straightforward for me several hours earlier, before Paul R begins to use `OR`s